Using pyparsing to parse infix expression
I am learning Paul McGuire's fabulous pyparsing Python module. I'm posting this for discussion and hopefully to get a deeper insight into pyparsing.
The following code parses a parenthetical expression that looks similar to a Django Q() object expression used for querying data. Here is an example expression:
'( title__regex=r"^(An?|The) +" ) | ( id__in=[1, 3, 4] )'

Here's the code:
import pyparsing as p

ident = p.Word(p.identchars, p.identbodychars)
cond_op = p.Opt('!') + '='
quoted_string = p.quoted_string
unquoted_string = p.Word(p.string.printable, exclude_chars='()\'"')
rvalue = p.OneOrMore(quoted_string | unquoted_string)
infix_operator = p.one_of('& | ^').set_name('"logical operator"')
whitespace = p.ZeroOrMore(p.White())
expr = p.infix_notation(
    p.Combine(ident + whitespace + cond_op + whitespace + rvalue),
    [(infix_operator, 2, p.opAssoc.LEFT)]
)

string = '( title__regex=r"^(An?|The) +" ) | ( id__in=[1, 3, 4] )'

try:
    results = expr.parse_string(string, parse_all=True).as_list()
except p.ParseException as e:
    print(e.explain())
else:
    print(results)

The code correctly outputs:
[['title__regex=r"^(An?|The) +"', '|', 'id__in=[1, 3, 4]']]

What other solutions are there?
Is there a better way to express a sequence of unquoted and quoted characters? Here quotes prevent parens from being interpreted as the end or start of a parenthetical expression.
If I mangle the input string by removing the = char, i.e. title__regex r"^(An?|The) +", the parser returns:
    (title__regex r"^(An?|The) +") | (id__in=[1, 3, 4])
                  ^
ParseException: Expected "logical operator" term, found 'r'  (at char 14), (line:1, col:15)

Why is the parser expecting a "logical operator"? It should be expecting "=".

Check out some of the examples (https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/tree/master/examples) that use infix_notation, such as simpleBool.py and simpleArith.py, and eval_arith.py, which not only parses but also evaluates the arithmetic expression.
Precedence of operations is important when parsing infix expressions - look at how NOT, AND, and OR get handled at different precedence levels in this short example:
import pyparsing as pp

logical_operand = pp.one_of("True False", as_keyword=True)
NOT, AND, OR = pp.CaselessKeyword.using_each("not and or".split())

logical_expression = pp.infix_notation(
    logical_operand ,
    [
        (NOT, 1, pp.OpAssoc.RIGHT),
        (AND, 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
        (OR, 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
    ]
)

logical_expression.run_tests("""\
    True
    True or False
    True and not False
    True and False or True
    True and (False or True)
    """, full_dump=False)

Gives this output (note how "not" gets higher precedence than "and", and "and" gets higher precedence than "or", and that this can be overridden using ()'s):
True
['True']

True or False
[['True', 'or', 'False']]

True and not False
[['True', 'and', ['not', 'False']]]

True and False or True
[[['True', 'and', 'False'], 'or', 'True']]

True and (False or True)
[['True', 'and', ['False', 'or', 'True']]]

With this template for the logical expression part of your parser, then you just need to focus on how the logical_operand expression will be defined (in place of the True/False literals in the example. Maybe something like
variable_name + pp.one_of("= !=") + rvalue.
Some other tips:

Avoid inserting whitespace terms in your parser if you can help it. pyparsing will skip whitespace by default.
Write out a BNF for yourself to think through what kinds of things you'll want to parse for. It will help as a kind of checklist of what you need to implement in your parser.
Your unquoted_string term will match a lot of things, even some important words like AND and OR. It is worth the trouble to make this term more specific.

